# Confused about websockets and java

Tags: java, javascript, browser, websocket, tyrus

I have been looking at tutorials like this, [java websockets using Tyrus](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/sample-java-web-socket-client) and I see a server implementation, a java client, and a javascript client. I was expecting only a server implementation and a javascript client to handle messages from the server. Why is there a java client? If I am running my application with a browser then do I skip the Java client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's just an example, they could have Ruby, Python and C clients too. It just shows that it's not limited to only Javascript clients.